# How to add a plot and strings to an existing image?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to add some plots and a set of strings to a set of figures I have and I'm looking for the best way to do that. Anybody has an idea?

Here's the original figures and what I want it to look like:

[image: Original image.]

[image: What I want it to look like/do with it.]

Comment: Do you need to save the figure after with the added strings and plots or only visualize?

Comment: Yes, I need to save the figures. I have about 4500 of these and I need to plot stuff in it that depends on the time (timestamp at the top right). I also need to add strings that will also depend on the time. Then I need to save them and generate a gif, but that I know how to do. I'm saving them in PNG for now. Also working on a solution using PIL.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would use `matplotlib` because it allows you to do any kind of plotting, labelling, adding text etc. on top of the image and in the end you can save it as PNG or PDF or whatever you like. You only have to make an image without frame and axes. For the text is pretty simple just use the [`text`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html) function, while for a subplot the easiest is to use the [Inset Locator](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/axes_grid1/inset_locator_demo.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes
from skimage import io

img = io.imread('Hv6gA.png')

img_h, img_w, _ = img.shape
scale = 50

# Create figure without frame
fig = plt.figure(frameon=False)
fig.set_size_inches(img_w/scale,img_h/scale)

# Create an axis instance that fills the entire figure
ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0., 0., 1., 1.])
ax.set_axis_off()
fig.add_axes(ax)

# Add the image to fill the entire axis
ax.imshow(img, aspect='auto')

# Add a text. Note that x, y are given in pixels coordinates
txt1_left = img_w * 0.03
txt1_bottom = img_h * 0.2
ax.text(txt1_left, txt1_bottom, 'Print string\nhere 1', color='k', fontsize=40)

txt2_left = img_w * 0.03
txt2_bottom = img_h * 0.4
ax.text(txt2_left, txt2_bottom, 'Print string\nhere 2', color='k', fontsize=40)

# Add inset plot
axins1 = inset_axes(ax, width="10%", height="20%", loc=4, borderpad=4)
axins1.patch.set_alpha(0)  # set transparency of the inset (optional)

# Plot in inset plot
axins1.plot([1,2,3], [3,4,5], c='r')

# Save figure
fig.savefig('test.png')
```

As you can see to make the scaling easier I'm using information about the shape of the image, but you can use absolute numbers in pixels. I also added the possibility to make the axes of the inset plot transparent (`axins1.patch.set_alpha(0)`).

The saved figure will look like this:

[image: Test image]

Comment: Thanks Francesco. I have a question though. How do you add the string "test" to the first image in the question above and add a plot to a small corner of the image like the second image in the question? I can add an image that fills the whole axis, but I can't seem to find a way to plot just in the corner of that image.

Comment: Ok I modified the answer to make it more specific to your case. As you can see you can pretty much do whatever you like on top of the image.

Comment: Dude! That's awesome! Thank you... I had a hacky workaround using PIL, but this will be a lot faster...